# Limit which business customer accounts can sign in to multi-tenant application using AD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, aad-b2c

I want to create a multi-tenant application where users will log in using Azure AD B2C. I will grant access to certain tenants that are our customers using policies. Only [business customers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/overview#authenticate-business-customers) from select tenants will have access.

I have a customer that requires granular control over *which* of their users can access my application. From what I've understood, my application [will be registered as a service principal in their tenant as soon as a user consents to the applications requested permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant#understand-user-and-admin-consent).

That as all well, but the service principal is only a kind of account, with access to certain resources in their tenant that was granted when the application was accepted. When the application has been registered in their AD, anyone from that organization can sign in. When someone signs in, [that automatically creates a Consumer account in Azure AD B2C in our tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-overview#consumer-user).

> The consumer user can sign in to applications secured by Azure AD B2C, but cannot access Azure resources such as the Azure portal. The consumer user can use a local account or federated accounts, such as Facebook or Twitter. A consumer account is created by using a sign-up or sign-in user flow, using the Microsoft Graph API, or by using the Azure portal.

Now, I have a customer that also wants to control that only certain accounts within their AD can login. So basically, a user identity should not be able to access a service principal?

Is this a use case that is supported, and if so, how do I handle it and what terminology am I looking for? I don't want my organization to handle any of this if possible. I just want to give all users in a tenant access, and then it is up to the customer to grant/revoke access to individual users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, As you have created a multi-tenant application it will be registered in your tenant as a Service Principal and for the customers tenant it will  be in Enterprise Application . So , if they want to give access to few users or a particular group then they can assign user/group to that particular Enterprise application.

**Example:**

Service Principal Created on my tenant :

[image: ![enter image description here]

It gets registered as a Enterprise application in other tenant So in there we can select Assign Users and Groups to give access to this Application from their tenant or they can set conditional access policy as well for specified set of conditions.

[image]

**Reference:**

[Restrict Azure AD app to a set of users - Microsoft identity platform | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-restrict-your-app-to-a-set-of-users)

Comment: You understand exactly my use case, and this answers my question. Still not entirely clear about this section: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant#understand-user-and-admin-consent in the sense that I can't find information about if it is an enterprise app or a service principal created in the users tenant. But it sounds like they might be the same thing?

Comment: Glad to be of help @jokarl, so  i mentioned in my answer for this "I don't want my organization to handle any of this if possible. I just want to give all users in a tenant access, and then it is up to the customer to grant/revoke access to individual users.".
So , by default when a multi tenant app gets accessed from other tenant after granting the permissions it gets registered in their tenant as an enterprise application service principal which they can use to control access from their side .